# Static files are not served but accessible directly. Django, docker, nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I am trying to dockerize a django project with postgres, gunicorn and nginx. My problem is that static files are not served. However in browser console I see all static files being loaded properly (code 200). Also I can easily access any static file directly i.e. `127.0.0.1:8080/static/admin/.../base.css`. Nginx doesn't show any errors in console either. What makes it even more strange for me, my `redoc.yaml` is loaded properly.

Here is part of my **settings.py** with static:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Here is my **main Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:latest

RUN mkdir /code
COPY requirements.txt /code
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code
CMD gunicorn api_yamdb.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Here is the **Dockerfile for nginx**:

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Here is the **nginx.conf** file:

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        location /static/ {
            root /etc/nginx/html/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is my **docker-compose**:

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn api_yamdb.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/etc/nginx/html/static
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: how are you determining files are not being served if response is 200 OK

Comment: The page is not looking as it is supposed to look?

Comment: I don't know about nginx but when I run APACHE Django apps I have to run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: @alvo No, it isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by adding `include mime.types;` into `http` section of `nginx.conf`